# Getting wrong number of Wick contractions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, symmetry, feynman-diagrams

Consider this lagrangian:

$$\mathcal{L} = \dfrac{1}{2} (\partial_{\mu}\phi_{1})^2 + \dfrac{1}{2} (\partial_{\mu}\phi_{2})^2 + \dfrac{m^2}{2}(\phi_{1}^2 + \phi_{2}^2) + \dfrac{g}{4!}(\phi_{1}^4 + \phi_{2}^4) + \dfrac{h}{4}\phi_{1}^2\phi_{2}^2 $$

It has symmetries: $ \phi_{1,2} \longleftrightarrow -\phi_{1,2} $ and $  \phi_{1} \longleftrightarrow \phi_{2} $

I am trying to compute the symmetry factor of this $O(gh)$ diagram:

[image]

Here, the left vertex corresponds to $\phi_{1}^2\phi_{2}^2$ interaction (which is proportional to $h$), and the right one corresponds to $\phi_{2}^4$ interaction (which is proportional to $g$).

I am trying to calculate the symmetry factor by counting the possible number of Wick contractions. (I am getting a symmetry factor of 1/4 but I have checked from many sources that the correct symmetry factor is 1/2 ). In order to make this question concise and easily answerable, let me frame my question like this:

**How many Wick contractions are there for this integral?** : $$\left(\frac{gh}{2!4!4}\right)\phi_{1}(w)\phi_{1}(x)\phi_{2}(y)\phi_{2}(z)\int{}d^4v\,\phi_{2}\phi_{2}\phi_{2}\phi_{2}\int{}d^4u\,\phi_{1}\phi_{1}\phi_{2}\phi_{2}$$

To get a symmetry factor of 1/2, there should be 96 possible ways to contracts this integral. But I am getting only 48 possible contractions ( hence a symmetry factor of 1/4 ).

2 ways for contractions among $\phi_{1}$ fields ( without forming loops )

4 ways to contract $\phi_{2}(y)$ with 4 $\phi_{2}$ fields at $v$.

3 ways to contract $\phi_{2}(z)$ with remaining 3 $\phi_{2}$ fields at $v$.

2 ways to for the remaining $\phi_{2}$ fields (at $u$ and $v $) to contract (without forming loops).

That's 48 ways. I don't see any other contraction that would lead to the diagram I am interested in.

Can anyone please help me in figuring out **what am I doing wrong???**
Let me know if I need to add more details.

(FYI, this question is very similar to Peskin Schroeder 12.3.)

Comment: Why do you have a factor of $2!$ in the denominator in your expression for the integral?

Comment: @SethWhitsitt
It's there from the Taylor expansion of the exponential ( of interaction lagrangian ). It's a second-order contribution ( being proportional to gh ), so I divided by 2! .

Comment: It shouldn't be there, so that seems to be your issue. By applying the multivariate Taylor series you should get $\exp(-g A - h B) = 1 - g A - h B + h g A B + \frac{1}{2!} \left( (g A)^2 + (h B)^2 \right) + \cdots$. The term proportional to $h g$ has no factor of $1/2$.

Comment: Oh. That does make sense. I will look into it along this idea in more details when I get some time. Thanks.  @SethWhitsitt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly pointed out in the comments, I was making a mistake in the Taylor expansion of the exponential.  The correct coefficient in front of the integral should be $\left(\frac{gh}{4!4}\right)$

The number of contractions is indeed 48.